# BlackBerry Convert String to HTML

Tags: string, blackberry

I'm working with BlackBerry development environment and I'm looking for a way to convert String to HTML.

I have tried StringEscapeUtils but BlackBerry doesn't support these libraries.

Suggestions will be blessed :)

Comment: I think you may need to elaborate a bit. What do you mean by converting a String to HTML? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find anything else (the JSON library has one you might be able to use), you could always create your own. Take a look at http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html for a list of the character conversions, then you can just do a search and replace.